# Interactive Choropleth Map - Highlighting - getcolor function

Tags: leaflet, highlight, interactive

I'm trying to create a map of bicycle routes which will get color from properties from geojson file. It is based on Interactive Choropleth Map. The problem I have at the moment is highlighting. This part of the code checks in geojson properties the colour of route:

```
function getColor(d) {
    return d == 'red' ? 'red' :
           d == 'blue' ? 'blue' :
           d == 'green' ? 'green' :
           d == 'black' ? 'black' :
           d == 'yellow' ? 'yellow' :
                'orange';
}

function style(feature) {
    return {
        weight: 2,
        opacity: 1,
        color: getColor(feature.properties.colour),
        dashArray: '3',
        fillOpacity: 0.7,

    };
}
```

It works ok but when I try to use the same function "get color" on highlighting :

```
function highlightFeature(e) {
    var layer = e.target;

    layer.setStyle({
        weight: 5,
        color: getColor(feature.properties.colour),
        dashArray: '',
        fillOpacity: 0.7
    });
```

It doesn't highlight in the colors from properties of geojson. It's probably some small problem but I'm still learning and I don't understand it. Could someone explain it and point a solution, please? Thanks very much!
Here's a working example (not full working of course as I'm still learning):

http://members.upcpoczta.pl/w.racek/mapa.html

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `highlightFeature` method, you have the `setStyle` method where you're referencing `feature` which doesn't exist. The feature is defined in `e.target.feature`. So this would work:

```
function highlightFeature(e) {
    e.target.setStyle({
        weight: 5,
        color: getColor(e.target.feature.properties.colour),
        dashArray: '',
        fillOpacity: 0.7
    });
}
```

But since you're not changing the color (and the opacity) you might as well leave those out entirely, which also solves the problem :)

Comment: Exactly :) Thank you very much iH8 for pointing me the right way.

Comment: No worries :) Already accepted. I will probably have some more questions, I have some more ideas for this map. So far so good!